# ICS converting to different timezone when it shouldn't

Tags: icalendar

I'm using a scheduling component in a Joomla site that generates ICS files in the confirmation emails. The site and server are set to Los Angeles time zone. The users scheduling the appointments (and me testing it) are also in Los Angeles time zone. However the ICS file converts the appointment to 8 hours earlier than it should be when brought into iCal, Google calendar, and Outlook instead of keeping it to our local time zone.

The developer of the component is testing it from a different time zone 8 hours ahead of mine. He says when he books from my site, it converts correctly to his local time zone and he doesn't see any problem with the ICS file.

This is the code in the ICS file. Is there an issue here that I can pass on to the developer that could be causing it to convert correctly when in different zones, but incorrectly when it's supposed to stay the same time zone?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:61d73f89b2993
DTSTART;TZID=UTC:20220113T163000Z
DTEND;TZID=UTC:20220113T164500Z
DTSTAMP:20220113T163000Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Clark County Composts:mailto:Pete.Dubois@clark.wa.gov
CREATED:20220106T191417Z
DESCRIPTION:Peter DuBois From: 4:30 PM To: 4:45 PM \nPhone or Zoom: Zoom 
LAST-MODIFIED:20220113T163000Z
LOCATION:Virtual Consult
SUMMARY:Training Consult
SEQUENCE:0
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Thanks
Karen

Comment: Hi Karen, if you are using Joomla, please join [joomla.se], you might find some helpful advice there and it is a great place to ask Joomla questions.  If your Joomla developer isn't a member of that community,  please ask them to join as well.

Answer (score 0):

Two points:

Firstly, DTSTART;TZID=UTC:20220113T163000Z is invalid.   One uses either the Z suffix OR TZID, not both at the same time.  See the 3 forms of datetime specification for RFC5545 at https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.4.  You can also use (use all as they differ) the various ICS validators.

Secondly it is perfectly OK to issue the ics in either UTC or Z format.  Any receiving application should deal with the timezone changes correctly depending on the timezone settings of the user.   Usually when a user says it's wrong, they haven't realised that their app maybe has a different timezone and/or they have forgotten about daylight saving.